# EF Core Exception: The property does not have a value set and no value generator is available for properties of type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using .net6 and efcore6.

I have a database entity called Notification, which has a primary key type of NotificationId.  I'm using type converters and value converters to enable EFCore to translate between the complex types and basic CLR types.  My complex type is based off an integer.

When I try to save a new record to this database, I get an exception that appears to suggest I haven't configured a value generator.

The full exception is:
*The property 'Notification.Id' does not have a value set and no value generator is available for properties of type 'NotificationId'. Either set a value for the property before adding the entity or configure a value generator for properties of type 'NotificationId' in 'OnModelCreating'*

In my entity type configuration I have:

```
        builder.Property(x => x.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasConversion(
                x => x.Value,
                x => IntIdValue.From<TKey>(x))
            ;
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
```

This correctly sets the Id type to be Identity, and a primary key as shown in the migration:

```
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Notification",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),

            ...
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Notification", x => x.Id);
```

How can I persuade EF to use the identity value generator?

Comment: Value converters don't run for null values.  Is that perhaps the issue? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft It's an interesting thought, but I understood that's how EF knows how to handle database generated values.  I have tried setting the 'value' to 0, but that confuses the change detection code due to multiple records having the same 'idl'.

Answer (score 3):

The exception is caused because the value converter received a null value. I managed to get auto incrementing ints working with strongly typed ids by making sure the strongly typed id is not null and by adding the following line to the property configuration:
`.Metadata.SetBeforeSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore)`

**Edit:**
There is a pitfall with this approach.

It has to do with the change tracking. Since ef core 3.0 and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14616), when you are using auto incrementing for your key and the key value is not it's default, the entity is added in the 'Modified' state instead of the 'Added' state. This is a problem for the current solution as we never set null for the strongly typed ids. We would have to manually begin tracking the entity in the 'Added' state (with the DbContext Add method) and other types of automatic tracking will not work (for example adding the entity in a navigational property collection for a one-to-many relationship). Official support for this is being tracked with [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11597).

Comment: I'm also getting an error (The property 'Weather.Id' does not have a value set and no value generator is available for properties of type 'WeatherId'.) Could you show your OnModelCreating() code? I can't get it to work with strongly typed ids (ints). I have to specify the ID every time I want to insert to DB. Thanks in advance